# Dynamically naming CollectionFS files (AWS S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3

folks.   I'm attempting to figure out a way to dynamically set the name on files being uploaded to Amazon S3 via CollectionFS (cfs:s3).

The following code is sort of a starting point, I just don't know where to go from here:

```
var modStore = new FS.Store.S3("modFiles", {
    accessKeyId: "--key--",
    secretAccessKey: "--key--",
    bucket: "meteor-intrepid",
    folder: "mods",
    beforeWrite: function(fileObj) {
        return {
            name: "RenameTest"
        }
    }
});
```

What I can't figure out is how I'm going to get form data into `beforeWrite`.  The following bit of code is the form that's being used to store files in this collection:

```
{{#autoForm collection="ModUploads" id="uploadFileForm" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
        <section class="centered">
            {{> afQuickField name="file" label=false}}
        </section>
        {{#if noMods}}
            No Mods!
        {{ else }}
            <section class="form-group">
                <label for="mod">Mod:</label>
                <select class="form-control" data-schema-key="mod" id="mod" name="mod">
                {{#each mods}}
                    <option value="{{ _id }}">{{ name }}</option>
                {{/each}}
                </select>
            </section>
        {{/if}}
        {{> afQuickField name="version" }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Upload File</button>
    </fieldset>
{{/autoForm}}
```

What I would like to do is pull the text of the selected 'mod' option, as well as grab the value of the "version" field, and use those to build the filename of the object being stored, but I have no idea how to pass that information where it needs to go.   Any help would be greatly appreciated, I know there's probably got to be some way to do what I'm wanting to do, I just...can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your template is called 'uploadTemplate', you just set up a response to a submit event, pull out the values of **mod** and **version** using the bit of jquery supplied my Meteor, put them in a fileName variable which you then use in **modStore**.

```
Template.uploadTemplate.events({

    'submit #uploadFileForm': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var fileName = $('#mod').val() + '-' + $('#version').val();

        var modStore = new FS.Store.S3("modFiles", {
            accessKeyId: "--key--",
            secretAccessKey: "--key--",
            bucket: "meteor-intrepid",
            folder: "mods",
            beforeWrite: function(fileObj) {
                return {
                    name: fileName
                }
            }
        });
        //do whatever with modStore
        //Router.go('/somewhere/togo/afterwards');


    }
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that `modStore` is defined on the server (server/s3-collections/mod-files.js), and that the template event handler would be on the client.   This does give me an idea though...

Comment: @MisutoWolf Ok, stick the modStore bit in a Meteor.method in server code and call the Meteor.method from the event. Meteor methods are described here meteor.com/try/10 and of course in the docs docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods